# How to prevent selenium test from skipping Assertions

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, assertion

I have a selenium test using C#. the test checks that links on a webpage exist.  the test contains different assertions and everything work but if one assertion fails, the rest of the assertions are skipped. how do i change it so that even if one assertion fails, the test will continue to check the rest of the assertions?  so this is the results:
skipped because of previous errors
Skipped in 0.001s

I used try/catch but it didnt make any difference

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it Nunit or xUnit you are working on ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Nunit

Answer (score 0):

NUnit has [Multiple Asserts](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/multiple-asserts.html) feature. This will store all the failures and report them when exiting the `Assert.Multiple` block. Use it to warp the assertions and other needed code

```
[Test]
public void SomeTest()
{
    Assert.Multiple(() =>
    {
        int intResult = GetIntResult();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result, "First assertion");

        float floatResult = GetFloatResult();
        Assert.AreEqual(3.3, floatResult , "Second assertion");
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks. is it possible to use  SoftAssertions. it doesnt seem to be  receognised  in C# with NUNIT                                 SoftAssert softAssertion= new SoftAssert();

Comment: SoftAssert is a feature of TestNG, not NUnit.

Comment: MultipleAsserts serve the same purpose. All assertion results are saved until the end of the MultipleAssert block.